# async function - Task Factory

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I was trying to wrap my "GetNonEmptyString" function in a Task so i can await it in an async method. The following code returns the correct string, but why is none of the Task.Delay statement executed?

```
Public Async Function GetDataAsync() As Task(Of String)
    Dim result = Await GetStringAsync()
    Return result
End Function

Public Function GetStringAsync() As Task(Of String)
    Return Task(Of String).Factory.StartNew(Function()
                                                      Task.Delay(100000)
                                                      Return GetNonEmptyString()
                                                  End Function)
End Function

Private Function GetNonEmptyString() As String
    Task.Delay(100000)
    Return "notEmpty"
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task.Delay` is not the equivalent of `Thread.Sleep`.

`Task.Delay` returns a `Task`, which will complete after a delay. In order to actually wait for the task to complete you have to `Await` the returned task, call its `.Result` property or the `.Wait()` method or use a `.ContinueWith` continuation.